# Efficient sub-array (2D) access

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

*NB: I'm open to suggestion of a better title..*

Imagine an `n`x`n` square, stored as an integer array.

What is the most efficient method of generating an `n`-length array of the integers in each of the `n` non-overlapping `sqrt(n)`x`sqrt(n)` sub-squares?

A special case (`n=9`) of this is Sudoku, if we wanted the numbers in the smaller squares.

The only method I can think of is something like:

```
int square[n][n], subsq[n], len;

int s = sqrt(n);

for(int j=0; j<n; j+=s){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i+=s){
        //square[i][j] is the top-left of each sub-square
        len = 0;
        for(int y=j; y<j+s; y++){
            for(int x=i; x<i+s; x++){
                subsq[len] = square[x][y];
                len++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this seems loopy, if you'll forgive me the pun.

Does anyone have a more efficient suggestion?

Comment: Seems good. What do you mean by "more efficient"? Isn't this already pretty efficient? The only thing that comes to mind is storing the matrix partitioned into submatrices in the first place, for cache efficiency, but that will only play a role for larger `n`. It's also not useful if you usually access the matrix in a non-local way

Comment: @NiklasB. It is? I suppose that's really a large part of my question. It just seemed nasty to me on account of a four-deep for loop. I wondered if there might be a better solution from the fact that the array is stored in contiguous memory.

Comment: @OllieFord: Well, you're not accessing the array in a sequential manner.  You're hopping around in memory currently.  You could improve your cache line performance by making your second index vary more rapidly than your first.  Aside from that, the loops are algorithmic and have little to do with a 2D array.

Comment: The four nested loops are inherent in the question.  If n is known at compile time, the compiler may inline away some of the loops.

Comment: @Ollie The total complexity of the loop is O(n^2), if you think about it. But I think the problem is that your question is unclear. What do you want to achieve? Do you just want a formula to compute the 2D coordinates of the element `subsq[i]`?

Comment: Edit the question to start out saying that n is a perfect square.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you @CamilleGoudeseune. How do you spot that it is inherent in the question? Because there's two dimensions to iterate over, twice?

Comment: @EdS. I think that's what I'm alluding to in my first comment - would it better to access one point in memory, and find the next position by addition/multiplication? Or is that just the same as `for`, ultimately? I suppose it must be. I don't understand your last sentence - you want me to remove the `arrays` tag?

Comment: @NiklasB. Again, sorry, but how do you see that it is O(n^2)? What I want to achieve, is actually what I stated - I want to just get the values in the smaller square, to pass to some other function.

Comment: @OllieFord Just count the number of inner loop iterations. One for every cell. You have n^2 cells.

Comment: @NiklasB. Thanks. So that's sufficient to say that I can't do any better?

Comment: @OllieFord Well it depends on your representation and what you want. If you represent the matrix as a 2D array and want the submatrices as contiguous arrays, this is asymptotically optimal. If you store the matrix as a collection of contiguous arrays of it submatrices, you can retrieve those in O(1). For example, `int grid[sqrt(n)][sqrt(n)][n]`. But then it's not as simple do do other operations with your matrix, so it all depends

Comment: @NiklasB. Thank you! If you want to write up I'll accept answer.

Comment: @OllieFord Yes, 2 dims each for n and sqrt(n) means 4 nested loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the four level loop, you are only accessing each array element at most one time, so the complexity of your approach is O(n^2), and not O(n^4) as the four loop levels suggest. And, since you actually want to look at all elements, this is close to optimal.

There is only one possible suboptimality: Incomplete use of cachelines. If `s` is not a multiple of a cache line, your subsquares will end in the middle of a cacheline, leading to parts of the data being fetched twice from memory. However, this is only an issue if your subsquares do not fit into cache anymore, so you need a very large problem size to trigger this. *For a sudoku square, there is no faster way than the one you've given.*

To work around this cacheline issue (once you determined that this is really worth it!), you can go through your matrix one line at a time, aggregating data for `ciel(n/sqrt(n))` subsquares in an output array. This would exchange the loops in the following way:

```
for(int j=0; j<n; j+=s){
    for(int y=j; y<j+s; y++){
        for(int i=0; i<n; i+=s){
            for(int x=i; x<i+s; x++){
```

However, this will only work out if the intermediate data you need to hold while traversing a single subsquare is small. If you need to copy the entire data into a temporary array like you do, you won't gain anything.

---

If you really want to optimize, try to get away from storing the data in the temporary `subseq` array. Try to interprete the data you find directly where you read it from the matrix. If you are indeed checking sudoku squares, it is possible to avoid this temporary array.

---

From the way you pose the question, I presume that your goal is to pass the data in each subsquare to an analysis function in turn. If that is the case, you can simply pass a pointer to the 2D subarray to the function like this:

```
void analyse(int width, int height, int (*subsquare)[n]) {
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            subsquare[y][x];    //do anything you like with this value
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int square[n][n], subsq[n], len;
    int s = sqrt(n);

    for(int j=0; j<n; j+=s){
        for(int i=0; i<n; i+=s){
            analyse(s, s, (int (*)[n])&square[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can just pass any 2D subarray shape to your analysis function by varying the first two parameters, and completely avoid a copy.